# Why does GNU find utility produce different matches on a regex to egrep, despite using regextype egrep?

Tags: regex, find

I wanted to use find to find every file in a directory that starts with a lower case.
A simple regex combined with find should solve this problem (I don't need to deal with whitespace in file names).

So I tried `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^.*/[a-z][^/]*$' -type f`. And it returned, amongst other things which I don't think should match, `./config/Config.scala`.

So I assumed my regex was wrong, and went and tested it using egrep itself: `echo './config/Config.scala' | egrep '^.*/[a-z][^/]*$'`. There was no match.

What is `find` doing that I'm missing? I'm already aware the `-regex` operates on the relative file path rather than the file name (which I dislike, but that's another issue). The find version is 4.4.2

Comment: What's wrong with `-name '[a-z]*'`?

Comment: Whilst -name '[a-z]* solves this problem nicely, it doesn't explain why the regex matches things I don't expect it to. I don't need a solution to the problem, but I do want an explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: Observations: 1. You used two quite different looking regexps in your two sample commands. 2. I can't reproduce the behavior of your find command with GNU find 4.4.2. What's your find --version?

Comment: The second one is a mis-paste. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce with this series of commands:

```
mkdir testtmp
cd testtmp
mkdir config
touch config/Config.scala
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^.*/[a-z][^/]*$' -type f
```

and got no output. I also have find 4.4.2, as packaged by Debian.

**UPDATE**

I bet this is a locale thing, with `[a-z]` matching more than the 26 lowercase letters we all know it should. Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^.*/[a-z][^/]*$' -type f
```

Comment: I have find 4.4.2 as packaged by Ubuntu, and, copying this verbatim, the output I get is `./config/Config.scala`

Comment: Bingo. The issue is the locale it seems. LC_ALL is blank, but it seems very strange to me that [a-z] should match uppercase characters too, unless something very strange is happening.

Comment: It's because the locale wizards decreed that the order of the alphabet is AaBbCcDd...Zz so [a-z] matches every uppercase letter except A. There seems to be nothing that can be done to convince them to change it.